# Shopify APP API

Tags: api, shopify

```
$shopify = shopify\client( $shop, $app_settings->api_key, $shop_data->access_token, false );

$products = $shopify('GET', '/admin/products.json', array('published_status' => 'published'));`
```

I am getting the following response by printing the $shopify:

```
Closure Object
(
    [static] => Array
        (
            [base_uri] => https://4f4b14c3eb5464ae238dd6cf4b88bce6:c2608b7067c5bf96028876023114b68c@pilibaba.myshopify.com/
            [oauth_token] => c2608b7067c5bf96028876023114b68c
            [private_app] => 2f996f1bd2a0f4fb343703555c89a234
        )

    [parameter] => Array
        (
            [$method_uri] => 
            [$query] => 
            [$payload] => 
            [&$response_headers] => 
            [$request_headers] => 
            [$curl_opts] => 
        )

)
```

after that accessing the $product i am getting the following error.

Fatal error:

> Uncaught phpish\shopify\CurlException: [3]  malformed in /*****/shopify_app/shopify_app.php on line 36 thrown in /******/shopify_app/shopify.php on line 67

Is it a problem with my access token? as i do have all the store permission while installing the app.

I did research for this error by didnt find any help either from shopify support team.

Answer (score 4):

change keys of your url:

apikey = c2608b7067c5bf96028876023114b68c

access_token = 4f4b14c3eb5464ae238dd6cf4b88bce6

```
https://c2608b7067c5bf96028876023114b68c:4f4b14c3eb5464ae238dd6cf4b88bce6@pilibaba.myshopify.com/admin/shop.json
```

Comment: Do you want me to keep the keys secret from being displayed here? if so, its a testing demo sites. or if you says i am passing wrong keys?

Comment: you are passing wrong keys, you must order as the example

Comment: Thank You benny. Yup you are right it was due to wrong keys. I fixed it and it worked.